# FrameLayout can not get focus with key press?

Tags: android, focus, android-framelayout

I have a view(Let's say it is `MyFramLayout`) extends FrameLayout, I can not get this FrameLayout get focus when press key(I am working in TV platform).

the layout is something like this:

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <com.roger.MyFrameLayout 
              android:id="@android:id/my_frame"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:focusable="true"
              android:focusableInTouchMode="true" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Anyway to fix the problem?

Comment: Look [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8684025/4385913) answer, maybe replacing `EditText `for `FrameLayout` it works.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you want your custom layout to get focus you will have to call

```
boolean b = yourLayout.requestFocus();
```

This will return a whether focus is gained or not.